# Twilio Browser Outgoing Call Not getting Event when reject the call from mobile

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I am building an application of calls with Twilio.

I can make the call from browser to mobile and its working fine. but I cant handle the situation when a call is rejected from mobile.

If a call rejected from mobile I need to show "The customer is Busy" in browser.

I have tried …

```
var outcall = outGoingDevice.connect(params);

outcall.on('ringing', function(call) {
            console.log('Outgoing call Ringing');
            if(call) $('.callStatus').html('Ringing...').show();
})
outcall.on('accept', function(call) {
            console.log('Outgoing call Accepted');
            $('.callStatus').hide();
            startTimerOut();
})
outcall.on('disconnect', function(call) {
            console.log('Outgoing call Disconnected');
            $('.callStatus').hide();
            resetTimerOut();
})
```

In my case when call to a number, it reject from mobile    -> going to inside ***ringing + accept + disconnect*** methods

Is there any busy method available in twilio sdk..? I am using 1x version for my project...

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Voice SDK itself doesn't have access to the final status of a call. What you need to do instead is register a [`statusCallback` URL on your `<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback) within the `<Dial>` TwiML. When the call ends, Twilio will send a webhook to the `statusCallback` URL with the parameter `CallStatus`. That status will tell you whether the call was: [queued, ringing, in-progress, completed, busy, failed, no-answer or canceled](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#callstatus-values).

You would have to send that status to your front-end somehow, but that's the best way to capture why a call finished.

Comment: I added the statusCallback url to twiML. Its only firing when the call is ends. Response having status "completed" only. I want when I hangup the call from mobile that send from browser, need to show  the user is busy. when a call is completed after talk its also showing as completed... there no quick webhook if when the user hangup (reject) the call...not getting otherthan "completed" in statusCallback !!!!

Comment: Ah, ok, you can try adding an `action` attribute to your `<Dial>` instead. That `action` will be called when the call completes, for whatever reason including "busy", and the parameter `DialCallStatus` should show "busy" or one of the other statuses. Try that and let me know if it works for you.